# A pesquisa do meu BD colocada em um listView(Arrayadapter) retorna o endereço do objeto e não o conteúdo

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Fiz um APP que salva a data e uma serie de números (8 números) no banco de dados do Android. Criei um objeto ( com data e os números), porém quando vou fazer a pesquisa de todos objetos dentro do Banco de dados e coloco numa list ele retorna os endereços salvos.

Código da função select:

```
public List<Hinos> selectHinos() {
    List<Hinos> lstHinos = new ArrayList<Hinos>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM Historico";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelect, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Hinos hino = new Hinos();

            hino.setId(c.getInt(0));
            hino.setData(c.getString(1));
            hino.setH1(c.getString(2));
            hino.setH2(c.getString(3));
            hino.setH3(c.getString(4));
            hino.setH4(c.getString(5));
            hino.setH5(c.getString(6));
            hino.setH6(c.getString(7));
            hino.setH7(c.getString(8));
            hino.setH8(c.getString(9));

            lstHinos.add(hino);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    return lstHinos;
}
```

Recebendo o retorno (lista) eu trato desse modo colocando num list view:

```
HinosDAO dao = new HinosDAO(this);
List<Hinos> histo= dao.selectHinos();
dao.close();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Hinos>(Historico.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,histo);
historico.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Porém no meu list view aparece:

```
com.estudo.app.historicootd.Objetos.Hinos@b706da7,  
com.estudo.app.historicootd.Objetos.Hinos@42a3666, 
com.estudo.app.historicootd.Objetos.Hinos@671c254, 
com.estudo.app.historicootd.Objetos.Hinos@89d85fd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está tudo funcionando conforme você programou. Na sua lista de Hinos (`lstHinos`), você adiciona objetos do tipo `Hino`. Portanto, se você imprimir isso com o `System.out.println`, por exemplo, você verá exatamente o que está sendo exibido no seu `ListView`.

Esse é o padrão do método `toString()` do Java que está implementado na classe `Object`, classe da qual a classe `Hino`, direta ou indiretamente, herda. O `ListView` chama o `toString()` de cada objeto para exibir o valor na lista.

Veja a implementação do método `toString()` da classe `Object`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Entretanto, você pode reescrever esse método dentro da classe `Hino`. Imprimindo o que você desejar.

Para reescrever, simplesmente declare o método novamente (com a mesma assinatura) e coloque a anotação `@Override`. Emobra a anotação não seja obrigatória, ela é útil para checks do compilador e legibilidade do código.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Novo retorno da toString() para a classe Hino"
}
```

Comment: Ar cantoni muito Obrigado...era esse detalhe mesmo foi apenas editar como queria a saida dentro da classe que funcionou. Obrigado msm salvou o dia kkk